# Windows phone emulator turns grey after several seconds after the program is turned on

Tags: memory, windows-phone-8, memory-management, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I have a problem with Windows Phone emulator in VS13, I am developing a quiz game.

When I run my program, virtual machine turns on, everything goes fine, after that it builds my program and finally it works, but only for several seconds.

I can do whatever I want during these seconds, I've even managed to start the game, but after 7-8 seconds the emulated phone screen turns gray.

I've checked what happens with the virtual machine in Hyper-V manager, it seems to stop due to lack of memory, am I right with this conclusion?

And if I'm right, what can I do to solve this problem with memory apart from upgrading my PC? :)

I'm using Windows 8 installed as a virtual machine via VMWare Workstation.

Here are two screenshots of my gray screen - one is WF emulator and the second one is the same screen, but opened via Hyper-V manager (it says "not enough memory" in the bottom line).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does the same happen when you publish to an actual phone?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no opportunity to run my app on a real phone, only via emulator :(

Comment: How much memory does your computer have before running the simulation?